# Could not autowire using method-level annotation @Qualifier in IntelliJ

Tags: java, spring

I've seen code like the following:

```
@Bean
@Qualifier("fooService")
public Foo fooService(Env env) {
  return new Foo(env);
}

@Bean
public Bar barService(@Qualifier("fooService") Foo foo) {
  return Bar(foo);
}
```

IntelliJ marks this wiring an error, specifically line 2, with the following error:

```
Could not autowire. Qualified bean must be of 'Env' type
```

However, the program starts up fine.

Why is this an autowiring error?

*UPDATE:* it turns out that this is an IntelliJ issue, and that the above is valid according to [Spring documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factorybeans-annotations). The clue that points to this being an IntelliJ issue is the error message; it seems to suggest that the `@Qualifier` annotation is attached to the `Env` argument, which it's not. I tested this with IntelliJ 15.0.6, and appears to be fixed in 2016.2.1.

Comment: A bean has a name (`@Bean(name="foo")`) and a qualifier is used to specify the correct Bean to be used in case there are many different beans for the same Object

Comment: I've editted, and added the wiring error.

Comment: Did you use the "correct" `@Qualifier` annotation from Spring or the `@Qualifier` from javax.inject?

Comment: @smsnheck, what do you mean under "correct"?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis serves me right for going on SO before I've had coffee.

Comment: Your question is way too broad. There's a million ways to wire beans together by name. Define _correct_ and _tidy_. What issue are you trying to solve? If it's the error, then clarify your question to concentrate on that.

Answer (score 1):

From the `@Qualifier` Javadoc...

> This annotation may be used on a field or parameter as a qualifier for
>   candidate beans when autowiring. It may also be used to annotate other
>   custom annotations that can then in turn be used as qualifiers.

By default, Spring autowires "by name", not "by type". So, if you have...

`@Bean
public Object myObject() {...}`

...the implicit name of the bean would be "myObject" and you would autowire it as a collaborator like this...

`@Autowire Object myObject`

However, if you want to name your bean something different...

`@Bean(name="foo")
public Object myObject() {...}`

You could rename your collaborator...

`@Autowire Object foo`

Or you could use `@Qualifier`...

`@Qualifier("foo")
 @Autowire Object myObject`